# laravel5.2 auth register the users table not found

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I change Laravel 5.2.43 Auth default users table to `user_list` and also set this code in the user model.

```
protected $table = 'user_list';
```

Then I visited `/register` but it give me an error *(see image below)*. It is strange that I create a blank table users, it run normal, data insert into the `user_list` table.

> **QueryException:** SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table `haveteer.users` doesn't exists.
>
> **SQL:**
>
> ```
> select count(*) as aggregate from 'users' where 'email" == walle@qq.com
> ```

[image: the error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected function validator(array $data)
```

Find this function. In there you should change users to user_list

Example

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
```

should become

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:user_list',
```